# Send Email weekly

Tags: email, postmaster

I want to send a weekly email based on time (no other trigger) that inclues channel entries which is defined in a template.

The recipients are always the same, just a few people.

I cannot seem to find a time-based option in postmaster.

Can anyone help? Another solution is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use CRON jobs to send email at anytime in the future. Specify a specific and/or relative date to give you the maximum amount of flexibility. You can even configure a parcel to send emails at re-occurring intervals.

This is directly from their Devot-ee page. You need to set up a cron job to curl your site once a week; It seems PostMaster allows for triggering emails via a URL. I'm busy and wish I had time to dig through their documentation, but I'm pretty sure you can just make a template, and you curl that path:

```
www.your-domain.com/notification_template_group/weekly_email
```

and just curl that with a cron job, and use something like

https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster/api/postmaster-base-api#send

to actually send the mail. You can probably use an htaccess block on that template page to only allow request from 127.0.0.1; then you're protected and only your server can curl that notification address!

**Note** Read through the docs. I probably just gave you a more complicated solution than is necessary, the people at Objective are quite nice (in my experience) so you can just shoot them an email and they can probably walk you through it.

Comment: Thank your fot the hint, I will give it a try with my limited capabilities

Answer (score 0):

There's a 1st party addon for this: [Cron-Email](https://github.com/EllisLab/Cron-Email).

It's quite old, but, since it's from EllisLab itself, I guess you can ask for help if it isn't compatible to the current EECMS version.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried that but the documentation is so poor that I never got it working.Unfortunately others already struggled as well, see <a href="http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18379/ellislab-cron-plugin-usage">[EllisLab CRON plugin usage] </a>

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out with a combination of Postmaster and Cronjobs. In Postmaster you do have notifications. Just fill them out, do NOT enter anything in the timebased fields and use the Expression Engine Mail.

Once saved, the notification will have an url in the overview. Just call the url with a cron job on a time based manner and you will get it working.

Comment: Cool! If I answered your question, would you mind my accepting my answer? Glad you got it worked out.